# function that gets field as parameters

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible to make a class function that gets attributes as arguments (not sure how this is named)

example:

```
class CrestAPI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://public-crest.eveonline.com/'
        self.urls = get_json(self.base_url)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            getattr(self, key)
        except AttributeError:
            print key

api = CrestAPI()
api.market.types
```

where api.market.types should print something like ['market', 'types']
So when the attribute does not exist, i could run some function with those arguments

Comment: this will cause an infinite recursion. the usual syntax/usage for `__getattr__` is outline in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

Comment: Did you want something more like `getattr(self.urls, key)`?

Comment: This is coming from a strongly typed background, but I'd try to avoid code _this_ dynamic because it's harder to test, IDEs can't handle it intelligently, and trivial changes to the backing API get pushed back into code using CrestAPI (so it's over-coupled and brittle).

Comment: Well, sortof. the problem is self.urls is nested dict, that can also return again a nested dict so i wanted to be able to use the .market.types as dict keys

Comment: Your custom `__getattr__` would only be called with `'market'`. `'types'` gets handled by the dict it returns (if you do `getattr(self.urls, key)`). And that's probably what you're trying to do.

Comment: David Ehrmann How would you suggest i approach the problem? Make individual functions? feels like a lot of double code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky.

In your example, Python will attempt to retrieve attribute 'market' from object 'api' first, and then retrieve attribute 'types' from whatever it received in the first step. So essentially you need an iterative solution.

However for an iterative solution the key question is when to stop. And there's nothing in your example that would tell the code "yeah, the parsing stops here".

It is, however, possible with a slightly different syntax, for example:

```
api = CrestAPI()
parsed_url = api.market.types()
```

In this case, Python will retrieve 'market' from 'api', then retrieve 'types' from result, and then attempt to call it as a function. This gives us the point where we can break the recursion and actually return the result.

A quick&dirty solution could then look like this:

```
class RecursiveRetrievalHelper(object):

    __items = None

    def __init__(self, first_item):
        self.__items = [first_item]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__items.append(item)
        return self

    # One possible way to break the iteration
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__items

    # Another possible way to break the iteration
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__items)

    # This is mostly for debugging and console
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__items)


class MainClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return RecursiveRetrievalHelper(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    this_api = MainClass()
    print this_api.has.some.weird.complicated.path()     # Uses __call__()
    print list(this_api.has.some.weird.complicated.path) # Uses __iter__()
    for url_part in this_api.has.some.weird.complicated.path: # Uses __iter__() again
        print url_part,
    print
```

Script output:

```
['has', 'some', 'weird', 'complicated', 'path']
['has', 'some', 'weird', 'complicated', 'path']
has some weird complicated path
```

You can then extend the helper class if you need more advanced functionality, as in it's current state it's capable of little more than returning a list of keys.